# Linq IQueryable FirstOrDefault calls trying to load unrelated assembly

Tags: c#, linq

I have an isolated class library project, part of a very large solution that performs various Azure Media Service functions, uploading assets, encoding etc.

I've used this class library as a project reference to other projects in my solution just fine, however when I try to reference this library from my main web application (web forms) and call the AMS functions it tries to load a completely unrelated assembly (crystal reports).

This only happens when using Linq expressions, searching for an `Asset` by `Id` for example:

```
var assetInstance = from a in _context.Assets
                    where a.Id == assetId
                    select a;

// Reference the asset as an IAsset.
asset = assetInstance.FirstOrDefault();
```

When the .FirstOrDefault() call is made, this is where I get a `FileNotFoundException`:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'BusinessObjects.Enterprise.Sdk.ZipLib.netmodule' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

My main web application project does have Crystal enterprise references, and the file pointed out in the exception does exist in the /bin directory which makes it even stranger.

Does anyone have any idea why the Linq extension methods are causing a lookup on a totally unrelated assembly?

EDIT July 18/18
Still not resolved, however I tried the following:
- Removed all Crystal Enterprise 2016 references: Code works
- Re-added Crystal references back: Code works
- Re-added Crystal implementation code, and I get the error about cannot embed interop, so I need to change the Embed Interop Types to False, soon as I do this it brings several other DLL's and .netmodule files into my /bin folder, once this happens, the error reappears and I'm back to square 1

Comment: What type is `_context` ?

Comment: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.CloudMediaContext'
and it's searching a collection of IAsset objects

Comment: Do you still get the error by targetting x86 ?

Comment: what do the `using`s look like for that class / cs file?

Comment: `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.Metadata;`    this code came directly from the msdn docs for AMS and does work correctly in other projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this issue, in case anyone else encounters something similar.

To clarify I don't think this issue had anything to do with Crystal reports or Azure media services specifically.

This came down to a simple versioning issue of the references installed for Crystal enterprise, the reference location for the web project differed from the installed Crystal Enterprise SDK but a minor incremental build revision.

I still have no explanation what was causing a Linq extension method to load an unrelated Crystal enterprise assembly, but nonetheless the issue was a different .netmodule was being pulled into the /bin directory than the referenced DLL in the project.